# Ads not working properly

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, ads, revmob

The following is code in my Appdelegate.m class:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
[RevMobAds startSessionWithAppID:@"Id"];

// Override point for customization after application launch.
return YES;
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{ 

[[RevMobAds session] showBanner];

}
```

The following is code in my ViewController.h class:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<RevMobAdsDelegate>

@property ( nonatomic, strong)RevMobBanner *bannerWindow;
```

The following is code in my ViewController.m class:

```
- (void)handleNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
if ([notification.name isEqualToString:@"showAd"])
{
    _bannerWindow = [[RevMobAds session] banner];
    [_bannerWindow showAd];
}
}

//RevMob required delegate method
 -(void) revmobAdDidFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
NSLog(@"[RevMob sample app] Ad failed: %@", error);
}

//revmob optional delegate method
-(void) revmobAdDidReceive {
NSLog(@"[RevMob sample app] ad loaded.");
} 

-(void) revmobAdDisplayed {
NSLog(@"[RevMob sample app] ad displayed.");
}

-(void) revmobUserClosedTheAd {
NSLog(@"[RevMob sample app] user clicked in the close button.");
}

-(void) revmobUserClickedInTheAd {
NSLog(@"[RevMob sample app] user clicked in the ad.");
} 

-(void) installDidReceive {
NSLog(@"[RevMob sample app] install did recieve.");
}

-(void) installDidFail{
NSLog(@"[RevMob sample app] install did fail.");
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 [super viewDidLoad];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleNotification:) name:@"showAd" object:nil];
}
```

The following is code in MyScene.m (my main menu) class:

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
    self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:(29.0f/255) green:(29.0f/255) blue:(29.0f/255) alpha:1.0];





    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"showAd" object:nil];
    }
return self;
}
```

Comment: Have you started session like [RevMobAds startSessionWithAppID:@"APP_ID" andDelegate:self]; ?

Comment: Yea I just tried it in my implementation file. Still the same debug message. Anything else you think would work @saidozcan?

Comment: I think you are triggering this IBAction before session starts, to wait it to start you can call startSession withSuccessHandler so you can enable user to trigger that IBAction after withSuccessHandler block called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using this method in StartApp. Try this.

```
//yourViewControl.m

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleNotification:) name:@"showAd" object:nil];

- (void)handleNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if ([notification.name isEqualToString:@"showAd"]) 
    {
        [[RevMobAds session] showBanner];
    }
}

//yourSKScene

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"showAd" object:nil];//Call with this.
```

Comment: When I put in [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleNotification:) name:@"showAd" object:nil]; It says use of undeclared identifier 'self'. I put it in my viewController.m is that where you put it? @Valar Morghulis

Comment: You should put in viewDidLoad

Comment: Hmm still not working. When I run it, it says "[RevMob] Starting RevMobAds" and then after it runs for about 2 seconds it says 
"[RevMob] Warning: RevMob session was not started"

Comment: can you show your appdelegate.m and view controller codes?

Comment: I edited the code at the top and provided all the code that has to do with RevMob.